# Trying to understand this code: map((data: SearchResponse) => data && data.items || [])

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I am new to Angular and am trying to learn by examining code samples.  I pulled some sample code for ngx-Typeahead and am trying to understand the code.

```
interface SearchResponse {
  total_count: number;
  incomplete_results: boolean;
  items: Owner[];
}
```

then

```
this.suggestions$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      observer.next(this.search);
    }).pipe(
      switchMap((query: string) => {
        if (query) {
          return this.http.get<SearchResponse>('https://localhost:5001/api/GetOwners', {
            params: { q: query }
          }).pipe(
            map((data: SearchResponse) => data && data.items || []),
            tap(() => noop, err => { this.errorMessage = err && err.message || 'Something goes wrong'; })
          );
        }

        return of([]);
      })
    );
```

The line of code that says:

```
map((data: SearchResponse) => data && data.items || [])
```

Reads something like "map the response into this function and call it "data". Then with this, AND it with the items (an element of SearchResponse).  If that AND is nothing, then return an empty array."  So what if it isn't nothing?  What does "data && data.items yield? Or am I overthinking this and data && data.items will return true so the whole data item is returned?

Comment: `data && data.items` will return `data.items` if data is not null. When using `data && data.items || []` you return an empty array if `data` is null or data.items is null/does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `&&` and `||` like this is a shorthand for `if`/`else` to check a value or get a default.

`data && data.items || []` is the same as `if (data && data.items) data.items else []` (or `(data && data.items) ? data.items : []`. That is, if `data` is defined and `data.items` is not falsy (e.g. a non-empty array), you'll get `data.items`. Otherwise, you get an empty array.

This works because in Typescript, the `&&` and `||` operators always return one of their arguments:

- `a && b` is `a` if `a` is falsy, or `b`
- `a || b` is `a` if `a` is truthy, or `b`

And because they short-circuit (only evaluate an operand if needed), you can use them to check a value before accessing it.

That means that if `data.items` exists and is non-empty, `data && data.items` will be that value. Otherwise, it will be a falsy value, and `(that value) || []` will become the empty array --- a default.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shorthand to ensure you're working with a properly defined value, in this case an array. When using an object as a condition like this, it behaves as if it's `True` if the object exists and `False` if it doesn't (i.e. null, undefined, 0, etc). If `data` is a non-null, defined thing, then the language processes the other side of the AND. If `data.items` is a non-null, defined thing then the expression short circuits. `true && true || ???` doesn't need to process the 3rd element to know the expression evaluates as true. But the expression doesn't return `true`, it returns the last evaluated condition, so if `data` and `data.items` are both non-null, defined things, it'll return `data.item`.

What if `data` is a thing and `data.item` is not? Then we have `true && false || ???` which can be shorted to `false || ???`. Short circuiting hasn't kicked in yet so we have to evaluate the third condition: an empty array. An empty array is a non-null, defined thing so it acts as true. It's also the last expression evaluated so the empty array is returned.

If neither `data` nor `data.items` hold a value, then the empty array is returned.

I don't believe it's possible for `data` to be null or undefined and for `data.items` not to throw an error.

In effect, all of this is equivalent to saying "I want `data.items` but if it's not defined, give me an empty array." It's fancy type coercion by taking advantage of the JS engine.

Answer (score 0):

correct - assuming 'data' exists and data.items exist it will return the value at data.items (which I'm assuming is an array) - otherwise it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I build a basic test to see how it work, `map((data: SearchResponse) => data && data.items || [])` after map data (truthy) and data,items (truthy) will pass { } in other cases will pass [] for the chaining.

```js
// let data = {"items": null } // []

let data = {"items": {} } // {}

//data = null // []

// let data = undefined  // []
 
console.log( data && data.items || [])
```